# Fix "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I have this code:

```
let index = findIndex(array: soldierCanFire, valueToFind: (firstBody.node? ?? default value) as Soldier)
if(index != nil){
   soldierCanFire.removeAtIndex(index!)
}

func findIndex<T: Equitable>(array: [T], valueToFind: T) -> Int?{
    for (index, value) in array.enumerated() {
        if value == valueToFind {
            return index
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I have seen some guides but I have not fully understood what kind of error it is and how to fix it

Comment: Which line is causing the error? But aren't you reinventing `firstIndex(where:)`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex

Comment: @Larme the first line when I call the method...this is a project that I resumed after 6 abundant years and was re-adapting it

Comment: The `(firstBody.node? ?? default value)` seems strange to me, but the best advice (after if possible in your Swift version `firstIndex(where:)`), would be to delete the line (or comment it), start rewriting it and let completion help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *modern* syntax is

```
if let soldier = firstBody.node as? Soldier,
   let index = soldierCanFire.firstIndex(where: {$0 == soldier}) {
     soldierCanFire.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

The custom method is not needed.

And even with your method it’s

```
if let soldier = firstBody.node as? Soldier,
   let index = findIndex(array: soldierCanFire, valueToFind: soldier) {
     soldierCanFire.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```